# how to get the DeviceID only from this ouput by using wmic command

Tags: windows, registry, wmic

I am writing a batch script in which I have to get the currently connected usb devices to the windows. I used this command

```
C:\Users\Virima>wmic path win32_usbcontrollerdevice get Dependent /format:list
```

its Output is

```
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&amp;2851D18A&amp;0""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_8087&amp;PID_0020\5&amp;15BBD570&amp;0&amp;1""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_0781&amp;PID_5567\4C530001030509109324""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USBSTOR\DISK&amp;VEN_SANDISK&amp;PROD_CRUZER_BLADE&amp;REV_1.00\4C530001030509109324&amp;0""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&amp;1C1548F&amp;0""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_8087&amp;PID_0020\5&amp;29432BF7&amp;0&amp;1""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_147E&amp;PID_2016\6&amp;32FEB3AB&amp;0&amp;3""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_0A5C&amp;PID_217F\70F3953D7812""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="BTH\MS_RFCOMM\7&amp;1FB43662&amp;0&amp;0""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="BTH\MS_BTHBRB\7&amp;1FB43662&amp;0&amp;1""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="BTH\MS_BTHPAN\7&amp;1FB43662&amp;0&amp;2""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_04CA&amp;PID_0061\6&amp;32FEB3AB&amp;0&amp;2""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="HID\VID_04CA&amp;PID_0061\7&amp;B449ECA&amp;0&amp;0000""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534\6&amp;32FEB3AB&amp;0&amp;1""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534&amp;MI_00\7&amp;1501E46C&amp;0&amp;0000""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="HID\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534&amp;MI_00\8&amp;F640D64&amp;0&amp;0000""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534&amp;MI_01\7&amp;1501E46C&amp;0&amp;0001""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="HID\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534&amp;MI_01&amp;COL01\8&amp;1473305E&amp;0&amp;0000""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="HID\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534&amp;MI_01&amp;COL02\8&amp;1473305E&amp;0&amp;0001""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="HID\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534&amp;MI_01&amp;COL03\8&amp;1473305E&amp;0&amp;0002""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="HID\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534&amp;MI_01&amp;COL04\8&amp;1473305E&amp;0&amp;0003""
Dependent="\\VIRIMA-009\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="HID\VID_046D&amp;PID_C534&amp;MI_01&amp;COL05\8&amp;1473305E&amp;0&amp;0004""
```

I want to extract only DeviceID from ouput and use in the registry search.
I am planning to do

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\$DeviceID
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR:

```
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %A in ('wmic path win32_usbcontrollerdevice get Dependent') do @REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\%A"
```

### Details:

The `WMIC.exe` command can get what you want.

`wmic path win32_usbcontrollerdevice get Dependent`

The real challenge here is how to tell `FOR` to delimit at the dbl-quote character, when the `delims` argument is already encapsulated with dbl-quotes.

`FOR` expects the second argument passed to it to contain any `'delims'`, `'tokens'`, and `'skip'` instructions, surrounded with double-quotes, effectively making all three a single argument.  We can create the same effect without dbl-quotes by escaping every space and special character in the set - the escape character is the caret (the `{^}` character).  With escapes in place, and telling `for` to chop/delimit the line at dbl-quotes, we're ready to chop the `WMIC.exe` output.

```
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %A in ('wmic path win32_usbcontrollerdevice get Dependent') do @echo %A
```

Now just mix in the `'HKLM'` info, along with the `REG QUERY` command you mentioned, and we have a fully functioning call.

```
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %A in ('wmic path win32_usbcontrollerdevice get Dependent') do @REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\%A"
```